# Analyze trends using Mann Kendall test in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have this dataset [DATA](https://github.com/livingstone90/Compare-CSV/blob/master/Copy%20of%20Temperature%20data.xlsx)  and I would like to perform time series and analyze trends using Mann Kendall test, anyone familiar with this

My code is here

```
c<-acf(df$value,lag.max=1)
dim(c$acf)
c$acf[[2,1,1]]
df$prewhit1<-c$acf[[2,1,1]]*df$value
prewhitseries<-data.frame(with(df, (df$value[-1] - prewhit1[-length(prewhit1)])))
autocordata<-cbind(df,prewhitseries)
MannKendall(autocordata$prewhitseries)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please, share your data with `dput()`, not external links.